# Struts 2 / JQuery : Disable and Enable Checkboxes On Single Checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox, struts2

I have a problem disabling/enabling a set of checkboxes based on one single checkbox button. I'm using struts 2 with JQuery.  I have 9 checkboxes:

```
<tr>
  <td><s:checkbox id="chkMain" name="Anywhere"/><s:property value="getPositionLabel('ANYWHERE')" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><s:checkbox name="system"/><s:property value="getPositionLabel('SYSTEM')" /></td>             
  <td><s:checkbox name="author"/><s:property value="getPositionLabel('AUTHER')" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><s:checkbox name="function"/><s:property value="getPositionLabel('FONCTION')" /></td>
  <td><s:checkbox name="reference"/><s:property value="getPositionLabel('REFERENCE')" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><s:checkbox name="constructor"/><s:property value="getPositionLabel('CONSTRUCTOR')" /></td>                                                     
  <td><s:checkbox name="content"/><s:property value="getPositionLabel('CONTENT')" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><s:checkbox name="materiel"/><s:property value="getPositionLabel('MATERIEL')" /></td>
  <td><s:checkbox name="title"/><s:property value="getPositionLabel('TITLE')" /></td> 
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

When the checkbox button "Anywhere" is selected, all the other checkboxes are disabled. 
and when it is de-selected, then all the other checkboxes are enabled.

How can this behaviour be acheived using jquery?

Comment: When posting code, please take the small amount of time necessary to make it reasonable--why not just unindent the 20 spaces so it looks reasonable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$("#chkMain").click(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop("disabled", this.checked);
});
```

That is, when `chkMain` is clicked, select all the checkboxes on the page *except* that one and set their disabled property to matched the checked status of `chkMain`.

If you have other checkboxes on the page that should not be part of this functionality you'd need to make the selector more specific, e.g., if the relevant ones are all in some containing object such as that table:

```
$('#idOfTable input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop("disabled", this.checked);
```

Or you could give them all a common class, in which case you could omit the `.not(this)` part:

```
$('input.someClass').prop("disabled", this.checked);
```

Comment: how can I assign a class to each checkbox in struts2? the attribute 'class' is undefined.

Comment: I believe you use `cssClass="someClass"` and that should be rendered as `class="someClass"`.

Comment: it worked when I added the class attribute to each checkbox.    $("#single_check").click(
      function() {
      $(".list_check").each(
          function() {
             this.disabled = !this.disabled;
             }
         );
     }
  );

Answer (score 0):

Try this, though not tested

```
$("#chkMain").click(function()
{
     $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).attr("disabled", this.checked);
});
```